# JS test if multiple of 10

Tags: javascript

In a JS function using setIntervall, I want to perform a jquery animation every 10 loops (in the other 9 loops, other animations are being displayed).

I am using the variable i in my function and it increments +1 each loop. Is there a very easy way to check in javascript if i is a multiple of 10 (in order to perform my jquery animation)?

In PHP I would simply do `if(($i % 10) == 0)` ... but I didn't find it in JS.

Comment: -1 just for no TIAS (Try It And See).

Comment: +1 for a legitimate question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Did you try it? I found a few sites that claim that the same operator `%` will work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 14):

The modulus operator in JS works just fine.

```
for (var ii=0; ii < 100; ii++)
{
    if (ii%10 == 0) console.log(ii);
}
```

Comment: For anyone who is just looking to see if a number is a multiple of another this condition is what you need. I would suggest using identical to rather than equal to for checking for 0 or false though e.g. if (ii%10 === 0)

Answer (score 9):

It still works in JS:

```
i = x % 10;
```

Here's a list of other operators:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp